# dispatch ngxs action in switchMap ignoring the return value

Tags: ngxs, switchmap

There must be a standard way to solve this, but I haven't found anything yet. I am probably not phrasing my search correctly.

I have a search input field and as is good practice, I use the `switchmap` operator to cancel previous http requests, when the user keeps typing.

I have based this off the example in the ngxs documentation:

```
this.actions$
  .pipe(
    ofActionDispatched(SomeAction),
    debounceTime(2000),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    untilDestroyed(this),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.store.dispatch(new SomeOtherAction());
    })
  ).subscribe(() => {
});
```

`SomeAction` is dispatched every time the user types something in the input field and saves in in the store (that's why `SomeOtherAction` has not constructor parameter).

Is there a better way to do this without having this empty subscribe block? This looks like an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way you could consider is to only dispatch the action to change the `searchText` in the state after you `debounce` etc.

Using the `valueChanges` Observable on the search input form control you could pipe through a `debounce/distinct/filter` or whatever combination suits your purposes before calling `store.dispatch` with your action to modifiy the state.

Then you'd only modify the state the minimum required times rather than each key press and could also call the HTTP request from there (and I don't think you'd need the action stream subscription in the component).

Doco for Angular Form `valueChanges` [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges)

Comment: It's been a while, but I ended up using the valueChanges method and was able to basically completely do without the actions. Much simpler, cleaner code. Thanks!